# Tor-browser doesn't launch after upgrade to Tails 2.7

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, mac

Tails 2.5 and Tails 2.6 were OK.  Tails 2.7 boots from a USB stick as usual, and things appear normal, but Tor-browser will not launch when I click its icon.  It will not launch when I click links, as in GNOME help, in Whisperback, in liferea (spelling?).  Is it just me, my old Mac, or something else, given the following possible clues?

According to messages in *dmesg*, something appears to be crashing at the same memory address and generating many lines of similar messages.  Sorry, most of it is over my head and I have not saved it, yet.  I will update this post with all or part of *dmesg* text after the next Tails session.

Some things appear to work (GNOME Help, Liferea, Whisperback, perhaps others), yet no matter what I try, Tor-browser will not start.  I await download of a new copy of the .iso as I type.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to start Tor-browser, *dmesg* showed the following, with the last two lines repeating many times:

```
[  837.685628] SQUASHFS error: xz decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[  837.685636] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x92e8cd6
[  837.685639] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read data cache entry [92e8cd6]
[  837.685641] SQUASHFS error: Unable to read page, block 92e8cd6, size fe4f4
```

Downloading a new .iso and installing according to [manual upgrade](https://tails.boum.org/upgrade/index.en.html) solved the problem.

Comment: it's a broken image problem for sure. Was your checksum verification passing when you've downloaded it, btw?